# Multiple actions were found that match the request with multiple PUT webapi actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, duplicates, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have my routes setup like this to allow action-based routing for my webapi controllers:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithIdAndAction", "{controller}/{id}/{action}", null, new { id = @"\d+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "{controller}/{id}", null, new {id = @"\d+"});
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "{controller}/{action}");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, 
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "{controller}", new {action = "Post"}, 
    new {httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post)});
```

Here are all of the types of routes I want to support. They all work except for the default PUT without an action. Action based PUT requests work just fine for some reason.

```
GET  users
GET  users/1
POST users
PUT  users/1             <- thinks its a duplicate route
PUT  users/1/assignrole  <- of this route even though this one works
DEL  users/1
```

Here is how I defined my controller actions:

```
public UserModel Put(int id, UserModel model)

[ActionName("assignrole")]
public UserModel PutAssignRole(int id, RoleModel model)
```

I would have thought that they are different due to the action name being different but mvc is not seeing it that way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you all an update, I have abandoned trying to do this with traditional webapi routing. I have adopted attribute-based routing using attributerouting.net since it appears to be the solution most are pushing to solve this issue. I made my decision mostly since the attributerouting.net functionality is being rolled into WebAPI 2 for VS2013 release. The syntax is slightly different but the features are almost exactly the same. Its a huge improvement. Even stackoverflow uses it for their routes, which helped solidify my decision even more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate the signatures of the two methods. Change your first route to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithIdAndAction",
    "{controller}/{id2}/{action}",
    null,
    new { id2 = @"\d+" });
```

and then change your second action to:

```
[ActionName("assignrole")]
public UserModel PutAssignRole(int id2, RoleModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and restrict the first routing definition to accept just this one action since it doesn't seem to be used for any other route anyway:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithIdAndAction", 
     "{controller}/{id}/{action}", 
     null, 
     new { id = @"\d+", action="assignrole" });
```

Comment: This route will still give you the "Multiple actions were found" error.

Comment: that would work if I only had one action that followed this pattern. I have many and having to list them all is a pain. So far the attribute based routing has been a dream. So much flexibility and it doesnt feel like a burden to setup.